# Sheets, conditional formatting

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, match, conditional-formatting

I am looking to create a conditional formatting function that will highlight "C2:E2" if "E2" > 5000 & "B2" does not contain the word "treasury".

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show some sample data for clear understanding.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/26cp3be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try on range C2:E:

```
=($E2>5000)*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER($B2), "treasury")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate in top menu to Format -> Conditional formatting
There you can specify range as E2:E29

Use conditional formatting with just one `AND` formula that refers dynamically to the values of the same row, but different column
AND comparision of the current value

```
=AND(indirect(address(row();column()-3))<>"Treasury";indirect(address(row();column()))>5000)
```

This can maybe be simplified, but definitely works with more conditions at once.

Some explanation:
To avoid typing new formulas for each row, we use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) joined with [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en)

`column()-3` refers to current column (the one you call formula in) . Have in mind that means for each columns (C->E) you need a different formula that refers to another column for checking if it contains "treasury". In your case you'll need different formulas for column C,D and E. column()-3 works for E, because `Treasury` is in B column (3 columns earlier from E)

P.S: translating from my native language, so not sure if English UI is the same, but should be intuitive from here.

Comment: Just tried that. It's not unformatting the highlighted cell.

Comment: this is what I did. https://prnt.sc/26cp3be

Comment: edited the answer to match your screenshot more

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a custom Conditional Formatting Rule.

Click in cell C2, then from the menu choose:

**Format > Conditional formatting**

In the dialog box, set your range:

`C2:E29` (or change `29` to whichever row is the last one you want to include in the formatting rule)

Under **Format rules** > *Format cells if...*, choose the bottom option from the dropdown menu: "Custom formula is."

In the field below, enter this formula:

`=AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("treasury",$B2))),$E2>=5000)`

Set your formatting style and click `Done`.